# QBWebConnector fails for the serverVersion ()

Tags: quickbooks

I am using the example file given in the \quickbooks-php-master\docs\web_connector\example_app_web_connector.
I have changed the example.qwc file as follows

`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<QBWCXML>
    <AppName>QuickBooks Web Connector example</AppName>
    <AppID></AppID>
    <AppURL>https://localhost/quickbooks-php-master/docs/web_connector/example_app_web_connector/qbwc.php</AppURL>
    <AppDescription></AppDescription>
    <UserName>username</UserName>
    <OwnerID>{90A44FB7-33D9-4815-AC85-AC86A7E7D1EB}</OwnerID>
    <FileID>{57F3B9B6-86F1-4FCC-B1FF-967DE1813D20}</FileID>
    <QBType>QBFS</QBType>
    <Scheduler>
        <RunEveryNMinutes>2</RunEveryNMinutes>
    </Scheduler>
    <IsReadOnly>false</IsReadOnly>
</QBWCXML>
```

`

The customer got queued successfully from the form.php but QBWC fails on update with this error.

> 20200430.06:52:36 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : Initiated
>   connection to the following application.
>   20200430.06:52:36 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppName:
>   QuickBooks Web Connector example
>   20200430.06:52:36 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppUniqueName
>   (if available): QuickBooks Web Connector example
>   20200430.06:52:36 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppURL:
>   https://localhost/quickbooks-php-master/docs/web_connector/example_app_web_connector/qbwc.php
>   20200430.06:52:36 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : *** Calling
>   serverVersion().
>   20200430.06:52:40 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() :  Error message:
>   Unable to connect to the remote server. Update cannot continue.

Answer (score 0):

If you visit the URL you referred to in your web browser:

- https://localhost

Does your web browser actually connect to it?

It sounds like you're not actually running a `httpS://` TLS-enabled web server on `localhost`.

Did you mean to use `http://` instead (no TLS?):

- http://localhost

Comment: The browser does not connect to https localhost'.
Does QBWC always need https because it gives an error if the appurl is not https?

Comment: If only requires `https://` if you're _not_ using `localhost`. `http` using `localhost` will work fine.

Comment: i got past that error and now i am getting
------------------
20200501.04:21:22 UTC : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setCurrentWebServiceSessionTicket() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\CurrentWebServiceSessionTicket has been set to 
20200501.04:21:22 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.CheckCFNResponse() : QuickBooks Web Connector example: Not a valid username and password. Job ending.
20200501.04:21:22 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : Done.

---------------
which is strange because i am using 'password' as mentioned in the webconnector example.

Comment: not sure why but the example code is using the username as QuickBooks but the log says that it is using 'username' as the username
20200501.04:21:22 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : Authenticating to application 'QuickBooks Web Connector example', username = 'username'

Comment: @KeithPalmerJr. Hello sir Can you please answer [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61819079/how-to-get-invoice-fields-for-mapping-in-quickbooks)

Answer (score 0):

ok, so I figured that piece out. The example.qwc had 'username' as the username and the config.php had 'quickbooks' as the username. 
so I changed the 'username' to 'quickbooks' in the example.qwc and it got past this error too.