# How to get invoice fields for mapping in quickbooks?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I am using [**npm quickbooks**](https://github.com/mcohen01/node-quickbooks). I want to fetch the invoice fields for mapping with my local fields. But could not find any API or function for the same or maybe I am not on the track. So can anyone please explain step by step **How to map our local fields with the quick books invoice**?

I can use [**getInvoice**](https://github.com/mcohen01/node-quickbooks#getinvoiceid-callback) but the issue is I have to pass the quick books invoice id in it.

```
.getInvoice("150", (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      return reject(err);
    } else {
      return resolve(data);
    }
  });
```

But I need only the fields for mapping.

Comment: Are you saying that you don't actually want to retrieve an invoice, but rather the actual schema for an invoice?

Comment: yes @MikeFeltman. From quick books invoices.

Comment: Quickbooks API doesn't provide that. They might provide their own nodejs client that might have something for it in there. For invoice, the best place to get the entire schema is here: https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/api/accounting/most-commonly-used/invoice#full-update-an-invoice.

Comment: ok but before `fullUpdate` I want to get those fields so that I can do mapping with my fields. No? If not then how can I do my first mapping?

Comment: @MikeFeltman could you post an answer with some explanation and example.

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say ***I want to fetch the invoice fields for mapping with my local fields***

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Just need to tell invoices(on quickbooks) that my this fields relates to this field. Just like in [this](https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/4818164/157da5ce4eeca4a6e512a282fc105597) image you can see I need to tell quickbooks that my weight field should be set to "some of one quickbooks field"

Comment: You are talking about these custom fields? https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/develop/tutorials/create-custom-fields#enable-custom-fields

Comment: @TarunLalwani Yes Yess... And if possible to change the other fields names (the third screenshot in link **INV28819**)?

Comment: I haven't used quickbooks. But looking at their API documentation there is a read preference API https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/api/accounting/most-commonly-used/preferences#read-preferences, and also https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/api/accounting/most-commonly-used/preferences#full-update-preferences to update the custom fields. You should be able to use these to fetch and update ?

Comment: @TarunLalwani Hmm not sure, but I think that is what I was looking for. How can I use them to create an invoice if you know this?

Comment: See this example. https://github.com/benexcellent2018/invoiceintelli/blob/1aa451f6c10634799fc278c6d7e0ad1cc92dd6cd/webhookindex.js#L31. So what you also need is a definitionId, which doesn't come back when you query the preference using the API. For this as a workaround, you can fetch an existing invoice and get the definition id using the same. You can then hard code this mapping in your code, or you can always start your program to generate the map using a fixed reference invoice

Comment: @TarunLalwani Yeahh!!! I made it till that. But the issue is I cannot use more than **three** custom fields. **:-(** It does not allow me.

Comment: That is a limitation the specify. Max 3 custom fields even on UI, not just API. So you can't  add more than 3

Comment: @DarkKnight, if this worked for you, I will go ahead and put an answer?

Comment: @TarunLalwani Nopes. I am going to another way now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The QuickBooks Online API itself *does not have* a way to get a list of available fields.

The closest you're going to get is to manually download and parse the `.XSD` documents that Intuit defines for the API.

You can download the `.XSD` files here:

- https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/develop/explore-the-quickbooks-online-api/minor-versions#working-with-minor-versions

That will give you data like this:

```
<xs:element name="CustomerRef" type="ReferenceType"
                                minOccurs="0">
                        <xs:annotation>
                            <xs:documentation>
                                Product: ALL
                                Description: Reference to a Customer or job.
                                Filterable: QBW
                                InputType: ReadWrite
                                BusinessRules: QBW: CustomerRef is mandatory for some SalesTransactions like
                                Invoice
                            </xs:documentation>
                        </xs:annotation>
                    </xs:element>
```

Which you could then parse out and determine which fields are available for which object type.

It's going to be super complex, and super time consuming for you.

You're likely way better off just referencing Intuit's developer documentation like the other commenters have already told you:

- https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/api/accounting/most-commonly-used/invoice#full-update-an-invoice

Comment: So you are saying i cannot create an invoice on quickbooks with my own fields with some customisation?

Comment: @DarkKnight You can't just invent random fields, no. Intuit has a well-defined schema that defines exactly which fields you can send it. The available fields are defined by the .XSD I linked above. You can take whatever data you want, and put them in the fields that Intuit defines, to create an invoice. You can't get the list of fields from the API -- you have to get it from the .XSD or from the documentation.

Comment: Intuit does have support for custom fields as well - they are documented here: https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/develop/tutorials/create-custom-fields  You define UP TO 3 custom fields. They have to be defined IN THE UI and cannot be defined in the API (i.e. you can _put data in_ the custom fields via the API, but you can't _create the custom field_ via the API)

Comment: ok so it is not possible what I want. I will accept your answer thanks very much

Comment: One more question apart from the above question if you can answer pls. Is there any api to get the details with which we log in to quickbooks?

Comment: There is no API to get the usernames or passwords, no.

Comment: I think this is what I need? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16197470/can-you-retrieve-the-intuit-user-id-through-oauth

Comment: You can use OpenID to get the person who connected QuickBooks, or logged in via OpenID Connect if you publish on Apps.com. It won't give you passwords. It won't give you usernames. And it won't work if they log directly into your app, instead of logging in via OpenID. If you have additional questions about that, please ask a new question instead of commenting on an unrelated one.